# How can I move member from telegram group to another group

Tags: javascript, python, telegram, telegram-bot

I wanna add members of a specific telegram group to another group. But there is an issue, I have a problem with flood waiting of Telegram.

Is it possible to add whole members of the group with their `user_id` to my contacts then adding them to my group?

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible because you can not add a member who did not save the ID in your Telegram contact.
it is  like to create a new group.
Telegram does not allow you

Comment: What about adding them to contacts by Id or username? then adding contacts to group ?

Comment: Telegram has limitation on import many contacts.I encountered the limit in adding an audience on my account because I added lots of numbers by programming to my contact list.